# Is there a term for a "double almost"?

Tags: single-word-requests

We are familiar with the concept of a double-negative, no? Is there a similar term for a "double almost," describing two consecutive modifiers that redundantly state that something is going to be but currently is not?

Here are some examples:

- "I was beginning to plan to start mowing the lawn."
- "The process to meet to strategize about potentially implementing the new procedures is underway."

Comment: "beginning to plan to start mowing the lawn" might be humorously over-specific. "The process to meet to strategize about potentially implementing the new procedures" might be deliberate obfuscation. It depends on why these phrases are used.

Comment: I've heard *It's too early to take a wait-and-see attitude*. Corporate newspeak uses excess words to hedge commitment: CYA.

Answer (score 1):

Generically, these examples are called **redundancies** (*[Routledge Dictionary of Language and Linguistics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Routledge_Dictionary_of_Language_and_Lin/O0-9Iw0Qh6EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=redundancy)* via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(linguistics))):

> In general, excess information, that is, information expressed more than once and which hence could easily be forgone in some occurrences.

Redundancy in rhetoric can provide further emphasis, including to a point of reversal: at some point someone isn't starting to mow the lawn but procrastinating; at some point the process is not underway but effectively stymied.

I have not heard of a more specific term pertaining only to your examples or the sense of a delayed *almost*.

Comment: This is where the 'rules' get in the way. I'd not rate this as more than a 'comment' (OP references redundancy, and could do the research himself).

Answer (score 0):

"I was beginning to plan to start mowing the lawn."

Try, "I'm just about to start mowing the lawn." This arrangement indicates that the project is about to begin.

Comment: They don't mean the same thing. I might have a 30 acre lawn to mow - which bits do I target first. I would need a plan. Starting the mowing would come after the plan.

Comment: @MathsBarry My lawn is at the back of my mobile home. The OP will have to decide which lawn the answer fits. :)